# Adding two numbers using stack-like arrays

Tags: c, algorithm

So for example, if I want to add 20 + 15, I need to have two arrays:

```
a = {2, 0}
b = {1, 5}
```

And I should get the following array as an outcome:

```
outcome = {3, 5} // or {5, 3} and read it in reverse order
```

The hard part is that I can only use the first elements of these arrays so that they behave like stacks.

In my example it is relatively easy, but what if there'd be numbers like `{1, 0, 0, 0} + {5}` ? Or `{9, 9} + {9, 9}`?

I can't really find one specific method to do this, not to mention I can't find ANY to solve `{1, 0, 0, 0} + {5}`.

C tag is here because I actually need to write this thing in C language, but any ideas about the solution would be welcomed (I mean descriptions, not necessarily C programs).

Comment: Can you push and pop from the *end* of the arrays rather than the beginning? Or reverse the numbers? Addition is done from least- to most-significant digit.

Comment: I can't do any of these.

Comment: But well, if there's no easy solution this way, I think I'll be able to reverse the numbers at the end if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the numbers so the least-significant digit is first and the most-significant is last. The algorithm for addition works from least- to most-significant.

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 1}
b = {5}
```

Adding these numbers should now be straightforward. Pop a digit from each, add them, and push the result onto the outcome stack.

```
a = {9, 9}
b = {9, 9}
```

To handle 99 + 99, you'll need to keep track of carries. That will be one extra variable that you store which doesn't go onto either stack. Pop 9 and 9, add them and get 18. Push 8 onto the outcome stack and store the carry digit.

```
a = {9}
b = {9}
outcome = {8}
carry = 1
```

Now pop the next two digits, 9 and 9, and add them to get 18. Add the carry digit to get 19. Push 9 onto the outcome stack and keep track of the carry again.

```
a = {}
b = {}
outcome = {9, 8}
carry = 1
```

Now there are no digits left on the input stacks, so finally push the last carry digit onto the outcome stack.

```
outcome = {1, 9, 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested) (**Updated to handle carry**):

```
Stack Add(Stack a, Stack b, bool carry) {
  if (a.Empty && b.Empty) return (carry ? a.Push(1) : a);
  int c = (a.Empty ? 0 : a.Pop)
        + (b.Empty ? 0 : b.Pop)
        + (carry ? 1 : 0);
  if (c>=10) 
    return Add(a,b,true).Push(c-10)
  else
    return Add(a,b,false).Push(c);
}
```

Of course, it is implicitly using the function-call stack as well as **a** and **b**.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How about now?

Comment: Ugh...you're making me think...I'll remove my comment since it no longer trivially applies.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best hope is an algorithm like this:

```
pop digits from stack a and compute number n1
pop digits from stack b and compute number n2
add n1 and n2 giving n3
push digits from n3 onto stack outcome
```

Failing that, you must know how many digits there are in each stack, `a` and `b`, so that you can align them properly.

An alternative, but less intuitive, representation could help, too:

```
a = { 0, 2 }
b = { 5, 1 }

c = { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
d = { 5 }
```

The least significant digit is stored first.  Now you can add and carry as necessary starting from the front of the stack.